# How to recover the hdp

Tags: shell, rest, hadoop-yarn

I have this command line to dispaly the YARN policy:

The result is:

```
{
    "id": 131,
    "guid": "4d9c3257-0998-42ea-8506-f773a368430d",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "version": 2,
    "service": "Namecluster_yarn",

        }
    },
    "policyItems": [
        {
            "accesses": [
                {
                    "type": "submit-app",
                    "isAllowed": true
                }
            ],
            "users": [],
            "groups": [
                "Application_Team_1"
            ],
            "conditions": [],
            "delegateAdmin": false
        }
    ],
    "denyPolicyItems": [],
    "allowExceptions": [],
    "denyExceptions": [],
    "dataMaskPolicyItems": [],
    "rowFilterPolicyItems": []
}
```

I would like recover just the list of the groups (in my case I have just one group is Application_Team_1).

How can I recover the list of groups via the API REST or shell if it's possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq`:

```
wget "http://myhost:6080/service/public/v2/api/service/Namecluster_yarn/policy/YARN%20_QueueName/" | jq -r '.policyItems[0].groups[0]'
```

Use `wget` or `curl` or something else that can output JSON data.

`jq` is filtering the string you want. Note the `-r` option to get rid of double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. jq not found.
In fact, I would like to display all the list of the groups.

Comment: @vero In order to parse JSON data, you need a JSON aware parser. `jq` is one of them. If you want to parse your data differently, please update your question with the tool you want to use. Please also update your question with the expected output data based on the input.

Comment: @vero BTW, if you want to get all strings for all group, you may use `jq -r '.policyItems[].groups[]'`

Comment: I'm using an API REST (HttpRequest), but for this case I'm using a curl in SSH LINUX because I should do a filtering.
My JSON data is the result of the YARN Queue Policy, it's in my question above.
And I told in my question that I would like recover the list of the groups, randomly in case exist just one group.

Comment: I can't install jq in my host, please how can I use grep. Thank you

Comment: @vero I'm afraid that tools like `grep`, `sed` or `awk` (...) are not suited to parse structured data like JSON.