# Extract string from JSON using grep

Tags: regex, shell, grep, rjson

I have a JSON input:

```
{
  "policyItems": [
    {
      "accesses": [
        {
          "type": "submit-app",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [],
      "groups": [
        "Application_Team_1",
        "team2"
      ],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I did a command line curl to dispaly the queue policy yarn:

```
curl  -u "login:password" http://myHost:6080/service/public/v2/api/service/YARN_Cluster/policy/YARN%20NameQueue/
```

It works fine.

Then I added `grep` to extract all the list of groups items:

```
curl  -u "login:password" http://myHost:6080/service/public/v2/api/service/YARN_Cluster/policy/YARN%20NameQueue/ | 
grep -oP '(?<="groups": ")[^"]*'
```

This following is the result:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   579    0   579    0     0   4384      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4419
```

It is not working. How can I do it using `grep` and not `jq` ?

Comment: What is the OS? `grep` version?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @papigee I edited my question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Os is Linux and  grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

Comment: Do you need to get `Application_Team_1` and `team2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover the hdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966502/how-to-recover-the-hdp)

Comment: @oliv, the requirement said no use of jq so, it is not a possible duplicate

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewyes Exactly I need to get Application_team_1 and team2

Comment: Try `grep -Poz '(?:\G(?!^)",|"groups":\s*\[)\s*"\K[^"]+'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good ,  
Can you write it in answer to mark it resolve please ?
Thank you

Comment: Ok, I see you are using it, I will post an answer.

Comment: Thank you , I posted another question is related to this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983265/bad-request-curl-with-grep?noredirect=1#comment88961456_50983265

Comment: That one is different, not related to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -Poza '(?:\G(?!^)",|"groups":\s*\[)\s*"\K[^"]+'
```

**Options**

- `P` - use PCRE engine to parse the pattern
- `o` - output matches found
- `z` - slurp the whole file, treat the file as a whole single string
- `a` - treat the file as a text file (it [should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file#comment44086821_152755) because when the `-z` switch may trigger grep *binary data* behaviour that changes the return values).

**Pattern**

- `(?:\G(?!^)",|"groups":\s*\[)` - either the [end of the previous match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) (`\G(?!^)`) and then `",` substring, or (`|`) a literal text `"groups":`, 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) and a `[` char (`\[`)
- `\s*"` - 0+ whitespaces and `"` char
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding the whole text matched so far
- `[^"]+` - 1+ chars other than `"`

As you see, this expression finds `"group": ["`, omits that text and matches each value inside `"`s only after that text.

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BaUWpC/1).

Comment: Can you help me on this question is related to regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065117/find-string-in-substring-regex