# Find string in Substring Regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a column in a DataFrame scala, that contain many string like this:

```
[Z12M1E][AGORA][Essai][CS_RES]ECO-56417-Escalade-ECO-56344-#incidentMajProduit#  Y2103      Y2103B0    S82NE      INCIDENTE             20180305   030403 20180305   030512

[Z12M1E][AGORA][Essai]ECO-56417-Escalade-ECO-56344-#incidentMajProduit#  Y2103      Y2103B0    S82NE      INCIDENTE   [CS_RES]       20180305   030403 20180305   030512


[Z12M1E][AGORA][20180305]ECO-56417--ECO-56344-#incidentMajProduit#  Y2103      Y2103B0    S82NE      INCIDENTE       Escalade 20180305   030512

[Z12M1E][AGORA][20180305]ECO-56417--ECO-56344-#incidentMajProduit#  Y2103      Y2103B0    S82NE      INCIDENTE   [CS_RES]          Escalade 20180305   030512
```

I would like compute the number of line that contain the string `[CS_RES]`, for exemple in my dataframe, the number of the line contain the string `[CS_RES]` is `3`.

How can I do it using Regex ?

Comment: Scala for Apache Spark

Comment: What version of Spark? Is the data still in the DataFrame or have you extracted the Strings into a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val str = "your input string"

val reg = ".*\\[CS_RES\\].*".r
reg.findAllIn(str).length
```

Note that the escape character `\` also needs to be escaped.

Comment: I think this Regex is fault, because when I apply it on a dataframe it return a small number, in another hand when I compute the number of the rows that contains the string [CS_RES] is a big number. How can correct it to compute the umber of line that conatin the string [CS_RES], as my exemple above, 3 lines contains this String

Comment: @vero - Regex code works fine. You most likely see some lines that contains `[CS_RES]` multiple times and such lines are counted as one each. You should analyze where your lines really start and end, what end-of-line delimiters you actually have in the input string/file.

Comment: Yes exactly, I should analyze where my lines start and end, thank you

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for the line numbers containing the String, `[CS_RES]`
Let us put your `dataframe` data in a text file, `datafile.txt` in the 
current directory of `scala`. Then,

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("datafile.txt").getLines.toArray
```

will read all lines into `lines` array of strings, `Array[String]`.
Now the following command will process lines containing the desired 
string and returns a list of line numbers containing `[CS_RES]`. I checked
this command placing the `sample data` you provided in the `question` and it is giving me a `List[Int]` with line numbers `1,3 and 8`.

```
scala> lines.map(x=>if(x.matches(""".*\[CS_RES\].*"""))
             (lines.indexOf(x)+1)else 0).toList.filter(_!=0)
res50: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 8)
```